# Jquery blur() effect on input and div

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am building an input field with an auto-suggest box that suggests content based on the user's partial input into the field. Kinda like the tags box on stack. The auto-suggest box is absolutely positioned directly below the input field and only appears once the user begins to type text.

I want to make the box disappear when the input field is blurred, that is, when the user clicks anywhere else on the site. Normally, I would just use jquery's `blur()` function to hide the auto-suggest box. The problem is that if I do it this way, the user won't be able to select anything from the auto-suggest box because that would blur the input field and hide the auto-suggest box. I need to find a way to hide the auto suggest box if the user clicks anywhere except for the input field or the auto suggest box. Any ideas how I could set that up using jquery?

Imagine it is setup something like this:

```
<div id="auto_suggest">
<ul>
<li>Jane</li>
<li>john</li>
</ul>
</div>

<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a timeout.

```
$("input, #auto_suggest, #auto_suggest a").blur(function() {
   $('#auto_suggest').addClass('hiding');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#auto_suggest.hiding').hide();
    },1000);
}).focus(function() {
   $('#auto_suggest').removeClass('hiding').show();
});

$('#auto_suggest, #auto_suggest a').focus(function() {
   $('#auto_suggest').removeClass('hiding').show();
});​
```

Updated to work well with tabs or clicks:

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/vUeeT/

Comment: When he clicks the link in the auto complete box it blurs the input and removes the auto complete box before the actual click lands on the target within the box. This solution works fine without a need to define or clear the timeout; setTimeout isn't setInterval.

Comment: @iambriansreed What if the user tabs to the link?

Comment: Updated it. @KevinB Sorry to dominate your answer.